# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method prepare()

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Im new to OOP. These are my functions. My prepared statement is not 
working :

```
function __construct($dbdetails){
    $this->_dbh = Connect :: getInstance($dbdetails);
    return $this->_dbh;
}


function sendData(){        
    $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES(:username, :email, :password)");

    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $this->_sentdetails[0]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $this->_sentdetails[1]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password', $this->_sentdetails[2]);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The error that this function gives me once called upon is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Connect::prepare();

Class Connect is from where I get my connection instance and I'm pretty sure I don't have a typo. Prepared statements are made on `PDO` classes, right? So why does my prepare statement take in `Connect` class but not `PDO`?

EDIT : This is my Connect class

```
class Connect{

private $_dbh,
        $_host,
        $_dbname,
        $_username,
        $_password;

public static $instance;


//the actual connection
private function __construct($dbdetails){

$this->_host = $dbdetails['host'];    
$this->_dbname = $dbdetails['dbname'];    
$this->_charset = $dbdetails['charset'];    
$this->_username = $dbdetails['username'];    
$this->_password = $dbdetails['password'];

try{    
$this->_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_host;
                            dbname=$this->_dbname;
                            charset=$this->_charset",
                            $this->_username,
                            $this->_password);  
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error : " . $e;
}
}

//creating instance for connection
public function getInstance($dbdetails){
if(!isset(self::$instance)){
     return self::$instance = new Connect($dbdetails);
}
else{
    return self::$instance->_dbh;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connect::getInstance()` is implemented inconsistently. When it's called the first time, it creates a `new Connect` object and returns that. Other times, it returns the `PDO` object in `$this->_dbh`.

`getInstance()` should always return the `Connect` object, and you should have another method for returning the `PDO` object.

```
class Connect{

    private $_dbh,
        $_host,
        $_dbname,
        $_username,
        $_password;

    public static $instance;


    //the actual connection
    private function __construct($dbdetails){

        $this->_host = $dbdetails['host'];    
        $this->_dbname = $dbdetails['dbname'];    
        $this->_charset = $dbdetails['charset'];    
        $this->_username = $dbdetails['username'];    
        $this->_password = $dbdetails['password'];

        try{    
            $this->_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_host;
                            dbname=$this->_dbname;
                            charset=$this->_charset",
                                  $this->_username,
                                  $this->_password);  
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error : " . $e;
        }
    }

    //creating instance for connection
    public function getInstance($dbdetails){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new Connect($dbdetails);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->getInstance()->_dbh;
    }
}
```

Then the first class should do:

```
function __construct($dbdetails) {
    $this->_dbh = Connect::getInstance($dbdetails)->getConnection();
}
```

Comment: `$this->_dbh`  still gives me a null value.

Comment: Thank you for conversing with me. I fixed my issue I added `DB::getInstance($dbdetails);` below my Connect class and seems to be working now (without the `$this->_dbh = Connect::getInstance($dbdetails)->getConnection();` part).

Comment: If you don't do that, then `$this->_dbh->prepare()` can't work, since you didn't set that variable.